# Why would my simple compilation fail?

Tags: c++, openmp

So I just install gcc from homebrew and I have a simple code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int size = 256;
    double sinTable[size];

#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int n=0; n<size; ++n)
        sinTable[n] = std::sin(2 * M_PI * n / size);

#pragma omp parallel for
    for(int n=0; n<10; ++n)
    {
        printf(" %d", n);
    }
    printf(".\n");

    // the table is now initialized
}
```

However, when I compiled, I failed:

```
    dhcp-18-189-47-44:openmp_code myname$ gcc-4.8 tmp2.cpp 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccFbBrPl.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccFbBrPl.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, if I change it to g++-4.8, then it is successful...

```
dhcp-18-189-47-44:openmp_code myname$ g++-4.8 tmp2.cpp -fopenmp
```

I am wondering why this would happen....

Comment: You could save some computation time by precalculating "2 * M_PI / size" and then multiplying the result by `n` in your loop.  Or, if you set your optimization levels well, the compiler should take care of it.

Answer (score 6):

You are compiling C++ code with 'gcc' (why?), so you need to link to it the standard c++ library. Add `-stdc++` to the build command. When compiling with g++ it knows to link with this library automatically.

- **EDIT**
  *On the other hand, your code has nothing related to C++ standard libraries. You have `#include <iostream>` but you use nothing from it. I think (didn't check it though) that if you comment out this include, your original build with 'gcc' should pass.*

Answer (score 4):

You're asking why your C++ program fails to compile with a C compiler, but compiles properly with a C++ compiler?

Then this rhetorical question is my answer.

The C compiler doesn't do things like linking in its C++ runtime. You need that runtime. Your linker errors show that the C++ runtime is not being linked. Because you're using a C compiler.

Comment: Just FYI, that's not a rhetorical question :D

Comment: `gcc` is not a C compiler, it's a driver program that invokes the relevant compiler. The C compiler is `cc1` and the C++ compiler is `cc1plus`, and `gcc` invokes `cc1plus` for this file, because it has a `.cpp` extension. So although the answer is right in spirit, it's a bit misleading :-)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Deliberate abstraction (much like what `gcc` does). We don't need to delve into the internals of one particular implementation, I shouldn't think.